# Getting the value of a constant in another controller is always returning nil using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In an attempt to get the value of historyRef in another VC, it is returning nil.  I have tried different solutions (including this one I am using) and I can't seem to get the actual value of the historyRef variable as declared in viewDidLoad().

The Firebase database has a node "history", which has a key (childByAutoId()) in MainVC.  I am trying to access that key in SecondVC.

In the MainVC is a constant:

```
var historyRef : FIRDatabaseReference!
var ref : FIRDatabaseReference!
```

Also instance is declared:

```
private static let _instance = MainVC()

static var instance: MainVC {
    return _instance
}
```

viewDidLoad() :

```
historyRef = ref.child("history").childByAutoId()
```

SecondVC

```
class SecondVC: UIViewController {

    var mainVC : MainVC? = nil // hold reference

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mainVC = MainVC() // create MainVC instance

        getUserHistoryIds()
    }

    func getUserHistoryIds() {
        let historyKey = mainVC?.historyRef
        print("HistoryKey: \(String(describing: historyKey))")
    }

}
```

printout:

```
HistoryKey: nil
```

My database:

```
my-app
- history
    + LSciQTJwR0VqwaAfKVz
```

### Edit

Rather than get from another controller, I got from Firebase.

I was able to get the value of the childAutoById but it lists all of them and not just the current one:

```
let historyRef = ref.child("history")
    historyRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            for history in snapshot.children {
                let snap = history as! FIRDataSnapshot
                let _ = snap.value as! [String: Any] // dict
                let historyKey = snap.key
                print("History Key: \(historyKey)")
            }

        } else {
            print("There are none")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you can see from my edit, I wasn't able to get what I needed from passing between controllers, so I just got it from firebase database:

```
let historyRef = ref.child("history")
historyRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        for history in snapshot.children {
            let snap = history as! FIRDataSnapshot
            let _ = snap.value as! [String: Any] // dict
            let historyKey = snap.key
            print("History Key: \(historyKey)")
        }

    } else {
        print("There are none")
    }
}
```

This gets all the random keys rather than the current one, this I can work with.

Answer (score 0):

You are initialising MainVC::historyRef in the viewDidLoad method, but just instantiating MainVC from SecondVC will not cause the MainVC to be loaded or displayed.

You can use mainVC = MainVC.instance, but you are dependent on the MainVC instance having been previously loaded and not otherwise discarded.

I'd be looking to extract any model usages away from being related to a VC, and passed to the VC as part of a segue when they are required.

Comment: Excuse my silly questions but isn't a sequel used to go to another controller?  I just want to pull the data from Main to Second.  Is there no way to get the preferred value or last value of the variable?

Comment: You'd be relying on the previous VC to hang around in memory even when not shown. That's bad. Try to find a better way. This _might_ be by creating a model somewhere early in your storyboard, and then passing the loaded model into a VC (e.g. SecondVC) when you load/present it (maybe via a segue). If your flow always presents MainVC and then SecondVC as a result of an interaction on MainVC then you can pass the model to SecondVC in the segue - as opposed to giving SecondVC knowledge of its predecessor. Without knowing the flow, I can't tell you the best place to load/store the model.

Answer (score 0):

Move the history ref from the viewDidLoad to init() when you initialize the MainVC. This way the method will run as soon as you instantiate the view controller. Also make sure that this is not an async call, or add a completion callback to know when it is done, as you mention you are using firebase.

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
   historyRef = ref.child("history").childByAutoId()   
}
```

As you instantiate the MainVC but never load it so that historyRef will never run.

Also having a view controller as a static is not recommended. I would rather pass the variable down through initializers or through view models.

Comment: I tried this and ended up with this error on the historyRef line: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value - probably because it hasn't been created yet?

Comment: Have you instantiated the ref variable? You need to instantiate it first before you use it.

Comment: since ref and historyRef are both references, I declared historyRef as var historyRef : FIRDatabaseReference! = FIRDatabase.database().reference() then override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        historyRef = historyRef.child("history").childByAutoId()
        
        self.init()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
then I get a crash in a declaration of var locationManager: CLLocationManager! = CLLocationManager() in the same controller : EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Could you post more code or send a link to the repository?

Comment: I have been able to get the value of the childByAutoId, but it lists them all and not just the current one... see EDIT #1